# Setting Sidebar specific <li> on active when overlapping a section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar with a fixed position in the center on the right. The sidebar contains an `<ul>`with `<li>`elements in it, aligned from top to bottom. When the sidebar overlaps another `<SECTION id="#same">` the sidebar element with the `<li>` where the inner `<a href="#same"><span>#same</span></a>` should be set to active. Or at least it should return it.

I am trying to use that script https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-overlaps, but the documentation is not so good.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5gjyh9tL

Comment: An example or jsfiddle/codepen would really help, you're not using the same ID on all these elements are you?

Comment: Sorry, here you go: 
https://jsfiddle.net/5gjyh9tL/

Comment: No the #same was just ment to be named like this because it should be the same in these 3 elements.
It is defined through an anchor given by a shortcode (wordpress) and my js creates out of the given anchor an ID for the section and then a link where href is the same and also the span text.